# How to find all "windows-line-break"-ed files?

Tags: linebreaks

Im on Windows which made Windows-style line breaks. Now it all should go to a production environment. With total commander, or anyhow, how to find files ended with Windows line break?

Comment: Files ended witch one single CRLF or files with lines ended with CRLF? Are you have a files with mixed line end markers?

Comment: "line-end-markers" I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Notepad++` and:

- search for files (`Ctrl+f` -> `Finf in Files` tab)
- search for `\x0d\x0a` string
- witch RegEx search mode enabled (`Alt+g`)
- in specified directory (`Alt+e`).

You can also replace CRLF line breaks to other...

> FYI: Total Commander also have RegEx search future, but I failed to make it work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which files are text files, for example by looking at the file extension, and if you have a Linux system, then you can use `fromdos` to convert the linebreaks.